# How do I overlay a rectangle with given coordinates on a map?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a map with counties (shown below) and I'm trying to overlay a rectangle on top of it.

Code for map, works well.

```
states <- map_data("state")
pa_df <- subset(states, region == "pennsylvania")
counties <- map_data("county")
pa_county <- subset(counties, region == "pennsylvania")
head(pa_county)
pa_base <- ggplot(data = pa_df, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) + 
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray")
pa_map <-print( pa_base +
  geom_polygon(data = pa_county, fill = NA, color = "white") +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA))
pa_map
```

The coordinates for the rectangle are:

```
     left    bottom     right       top 
-77.04933  41.60288 -76.53023  41.24093
```

I've tried using this, but it just shows the map with nothing on top.

```
ggplot(pa_map) + 
  geom_sf(xlim=-77.04933, ylim=41.60288, xmax=-76.53023, ymax=41.24093)
  geom_sf(fill = NA , color = "gray50", size = 0.5)
```

What I did get back was this:

> Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by
> `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class gg/ggplot

I'm not sure what to do. Help would be appreciated. I just want to put a rectangle on the map, given the coordinates I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved like so. Put the coordinates defining the rectangle in a dataframe and use this df to add another  `geom_polygon` layer to your plot like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(usmap)

states <- map_data("state")
pa_df <- subset(states, region == "pennsylvania")
counties <- map_data("county")
pa_county <- subset(counties, region == "pennsylvania")
head(pa_county)
#>            long      lat group order       region subregion
#> 64743 -77.44670 39.96954  2213 64743 pennsylvania     adams
#> 64744 -77.42952 39.98672  2213 64744 pennsylvania     adams
#> 64745 -77.37222 40.00391  2213 64745 pennsylvania     adams
#> 64746 -77.32065 40.01537  2213 64746 pennsylvania     adams
#> 64747 -77.23471 40.02683  2213 64747 pennsylvania     adams
#> 64748 -77.18887 40.03256  2213 64748 pennsylvania     adams
pa_base <- ggplot(data = pa_df, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) + 
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray")
pa_map <- pa_base +
  geom_polygon(data = pa_county, fill = NA, color = "white") +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)

rect <- data.frame(
  x = c(-77.04933, -76.5302, -76.5302, -77.04933),
  y = c(41.60288, 41.60288, 41.24093, 41.24093)
)

pa_map +
  geom_polygon(data = rect, aes(x, y, group = 1), fill = "red", color = "white")
```

[image]